# Rotating and elevating platform

Tags: technic

I want to build a platform that can be raised and lowered but also rotate at the same time. Tried scissors and linear actuator, etc. and other techniques but cannot figure out a way to raise and rotate at the same time.

Comment: Hi Ken, welcome to Bricks SE! We will find your question a whole lot easier to answer if you include more information about what you are building, and if possible a photo (or rendering) of what you have so far.

Comment: maybe the parts 73763 and 73764 will help?

Comment: What should be the range of vertical motion? How far should it be able to rotate (maybe unlimited)? Should the rotation and movement be coupled as to happen at the same time or should they be independent? How big should / can the platform be?

Answer (score -1):

They are many ways for a "Lift and Rotate" platform.

The easiest way to do this is by using the rotary part [73763](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=73763#T=C&C=86) (Technic, Gear Worm Screw 6L) and the stationary part [73764](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=73764#T=C&C=11) (its housing), and a Technic Small Linear Actuator on the bottom that stays in the fixed rotation.

The second alternative is to use gear racks and bevel gears for the same effect.